# Change Text Loaded By JS/AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm customising a UI for a piece of equipment that is purchased from a 3rd party.

By default the 'web manager' interface can only be customised to the extent of colours etc using an overriding style sheet.

However, I need to change a small piece of text. This text is loaded into a table via Javascript. The corresponding HTML page is literally just a couple of containers into which the JS loads the actual content and info from the device.

The piece of text I need to edit is in a table cell with an ID="status.Device.Name", so should be targetable, but I can't seem to grab it using via Firebug.

The content is present as such:

```
<tr>
 <td>Product Type:</td>
 <td id="status.Device.Name" colspan="2">TEXT TO BE REPLACED</td>
</tr>
```

Ive tried making the changes with:

```
$("#status.Device.Name").text("New Name");
```

or

```
$("#status.Device.Name").html("New Name");
```

Neither of these work. Any ideas what I should try?

To recap/clarify...

The text is located inside a table cell with a known id. The table and all data is loaded by some JavaScript from the device into the basic html page. Thus if I look at the source html of the active page, all I see is the basic html structure and none of the JS content.

Comment: The selectors you described `$("#status.Device.Name")` target an element with the id status and the classes Device and Name, for example:

`<td id="status" class="Device Name">Old Name</td>`

Is this your intention? Your description otherwise does not mention any classes, thus my confusion.

Comment: @jomikr Unfortunately, that is the actual field id. Ive updated my question, and hopefully my situation is a little clearer.

Comment: @Sari - I didn't realise the '.' was an issue until pointed it out.

Comment: Just out of interest.... How can this be a duplicate if I don't know that the problem is down to an issue Ive never encountered bwefore???? Surely the solution is a duplicate rather than the question??!?!?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$("#status.Device.Name").text("New Name");
```

Use this:

```
$("#status\\.Device\\.Name").text("New Name");
```

Reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)